# Swift. Doesn't show data on my screen. iOS and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I faced such problem. When I launch the ios application, I get a white screen and the data that I take from Firebase is not displayed. How can i fix this problem? I would be grateful for your favorite recommendations for solving my problem

This is my ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cv: UICollectionView!

    var channel = [Channel]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        self.cv.delegate = self
        self.cv.dataSource = self
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("content").getDocuments() {( quarySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("error")
            } else {
                for document in quarySnapshot!.documents {
                    if let name = document.data()["title"] as? Channel {
                        self.channel.append(name)
                    }
                    if let subtitle = document.data()["subtitle"] as? Channel {
                        self.channel.append(subtitle)
                    }
                    
        }
                self.cv.reloadData()

            }
}

    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return channel.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell
        let channel = channel[indexPath.row]
        cell.setup(channel: channel)
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

This is my Model

```
struct Content {
    let contents: [Channel]
}

struct Channel {
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
}
```

This is my Cell

```
class ContentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var channelText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitle: UITextView!
    
    func setup(channel: Channel) {
        channelText.text = channel.title
        subtitle.text = channel.subtitle
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs more inormation. Did you debug this? How far did you get? What happens if you inject static data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show data in my application? Swift and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110335/how-to-show-data-in-my-application-swift-and-firebase)

Comment: Well, there are a number of coding errors; for example `document.data()["title"] as? Channel` but `title` is a String `let title: String` not a Channel so that fails and your array is not populated. Either read them in as the correct type `name = document.data()["title"] as? String` and then instantiate and populate a Channel object OR use [Codable](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/) objects. I am marking this question as a typo unless more data is presented.

Answer (score 0):

The data retrieved from `Firestore` can't just magically be cast to your custom type (`Channel`); it's a simple dictionary. You eighter need to use `Codable` or do it manually like so:

I can't tell how exactly to convert it as you have not shared the structure of your data in `Firestore`, but I assume this will work:

```
db.collection("content").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let snapshot = snapshot {
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    if let title = data["title"] as? String,
                       let subtitle = data["subtitle"] as? String {
                        
                        self.channel.append(Channel(title: title, subtitle: subtitle))
                    }
                }
            }
            
            self.cv.reloadData()
        }
```